# Como remover pontilhado sob um link

Tags: css, html5

Estou editando um theme de tumblr e inseri 3 links no header. Porém ao inserir esse links apareceu uma linha pontilhada abaixo e não consigo remover. Como eu poderia removê-las no CSS?
[image: Linha pontilhada em link]

Comment: Poste o CSS. Somente com a imagem não temos como ajudar.

Comment: "3 links no header". Você colocou três novos CSSs na sua página?

Comment: 5 negativos. Nem perguntas piores tem 5 negativos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo visto isso é uma borda. Apenas faça isso no CSS no elemento correto:

```
border: none;
```

Comment: Depois vocês me banem por eu negativar sem dar explicações. Qual a explicação desse negativo ? Vocês estão mutilando de negativos a pergunta, mas nem sequer ajuda o usuário a melhorá-la.

Comment: Cara, a unica explicação que cabe aqui é a tradução de `border` e `none`, por que é óbvio o que eles fazem, rsrs,

Answer (score 3):

Se não for border pode ser ***text-decoration***, coloque o valor de ***none*** ou ***transparent*** para ele que pode resolver.

Comment: Realmente isso @PyMaria, parabéns pela ajuda a comunidade.